# How to configure NGIX to do not overwrite SSL certificate of Apache

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache-2.4

I need to proxy HTTP requests over NGnix.
However I would like that SSL is managed only by Apache server.

Is it possibile to configure NGINX to don't act asterminal endpoint of SSL and just being "trasparent" forwarding che connection to Apache in order to use it's already installed SSL?

Comment: Recent versions of nginx can do this, but haproxy is much better at it.

Comment: If you still need nginx, check out http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html and https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/